# Deblur an image using scikit-image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I am trying to use [skimage.restoration.wiener](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.wiener), but I always end up with an image with a bunch of 1 (or -1), what am I doing wrong? The original image comes from [Uni of Waterloo](http://links.uwaterloo.ca/Repository.html).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
from skimage import color, data, restoration
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

def main():
  image = imread("/Users/gsamaras/Downloads/boat.tif")
  psf = np.ones((5, 5)) / 25
  image = conv2(image, psf, 'same')
  image += 0.1 * image.std() * np.random.standard_normal(image.shape)

  deconvolved = restoration.wiener(image, psf, 0.00001)
  print deconvolved
  print image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
[[ 1. -1.  1. ...,  1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1.  1. ..., -1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1.  1.  1.]
 ..., 
 [ 1.  1.  1. ...,  1. -1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ..., -1.  1. -1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1. ..., -1.  1.  1.]]
[[  62.73526298   77.84202199   94.1563234  ...,   85.12442365
    69.80579057   48.74330501]
 [  74.79638704  101.6248559   143.09978769 ...,  100.07197414
    94.34431216   59.72199141]
 [  96.41589893  132.53865314  161.8286996  ...,  137.17602535
   117.72691238   80.38638741]
 ..., 
 [  82.87641732  122.23168689  146.14129645 ...,  102.01214025
    75.03217549   59.78417916]
 [  74.25240964  100.64285679  127.38475015 ...,   88.04694654
    66.34568789   46.72457454]
 [  42.53382524   79.48377311   88.65000364 ...,   50.84624022
    36.45044106   33.22771889]]
```

And I tried several values. What am I missing?

Comment: Hard to debug without using a standard-image everyone can use. You should use ```clip=False``` as a start to see which kind of values are generated by the filter (which are automatically clipped to -1,1 as explained in the docs). Maybe the filter wants you to prepare the input in the 0,1 float-range (e.g. using img_as_float) but i'm not sure; i would try this too. Remark: in all ML-based formulations i know of, regulization-variables are are always positive. I would be scared of using something like ```-100000```. If this is used to balance two components, it's always possible to use pos-vals.

Comment: I don't have any theoretical idea about that filter, but check the formula within the docs and think about your balance-variable beeing negative. What kind of effects are possible then. Maybe this is one cause of your problem. But i'm just guessing.

Comment: @sascha updated, `clip=False` must be the answer! You can check yourself, I have shared the link of publicly available image. That negative value was a desperate try. I feel that the value should be close to 10^-4, or something...1 seems to work best! :O Would you like to post an answer? ;)

Comment: I don't feel that's enough for an answer. It really looks like it boils down to the assumptions about the image-representation (float in 0-1 vs. float in 0-255; the latter seems not to be a good thing as the 0-255 ranges within scikit-learn are typically uint8-based i think). Clipping also is default which calls for some experiments about the input-types you use.I'm glad it's now working for you, but i think there is more to discover about those hidden assumptions(i think there is a special part in the docs about those types and ranges within the docs).Maybe img_as_float before is more concise

Comment: Well @sascha the image is in the link, the code is there too, you could try out yourself if you want! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best so far solution is:

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imfilter, imread
from skimage import color, data, restoration
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

def main():
  image = imread("/Users/gsamaras/Downloads/boat.tif")
  #plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray')
  #plt.show()
  #blurred_arr = imfilter(arr, "blur")
  psf = np.ones((5, 5)) / 25
  image = conv2(image, psf, 'same')
  image += 0.1 * image.std() * np.random.standard_normal(image.shape)

  deconvolved = restoration.wiener(image, psf, 1, clip=False)
  #print deconvolved
  plt.imshow(deconvolved, cmap='gray')
  plt.show()
  #print image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Much smaller values in `restoration.wiener()` lead to images that appear like you have put a non-transparent overlay above it (like [this](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ljyhRfysqxo/UhcDG4gyrUI/AAAAAAABexk/cfX6P9tR2-Q/s1600/semedakia1.jpg)). On the other hand as this value grows the image blurs more and more. A value near 1 seems to work best and deblur the image.

Worthnoting is the fact that the smaller this value (I mean the [balance](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.wiener), the greater the image size is.

---

<sub>PS - I am open to new answers.</sub>

Comment: You can also try convolving with `[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 8, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]`

Comment: Hmm @JeruLuke, as my PM says I am open to new answers, so you can post one, explaining your comment! (= Also I see that you didn't upvote my answer, regardless of the fact that you read it- does that mean I should delete it?

Comment: I usually play with OpenCV. And I have not not tried out your code snippet. By not voting, I am not at all saying you should delete it. Since the matrix mentioned above worked for me, I thought of mentioning it, that's all. :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the 1s problem is to either use `clip = False` or to convert the data to be on a `[0,1]` scale.