# Image de-blurring

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, scikit-image, grayscale

This post is divided in two

---

**Part One**

I have a little issue converting an image from grayscale back to RGB.

Image in question:

[image]

I use this code to convert it:

```
equ = cv2.cvtColor(equ, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
```

without any success though...

---

**Part Two**

Moreover I need to de-blur such image. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019222/deblur-an-image-using-scikit-image) I found some code that uses a wiener filter to do so, but when I implement it it doesn't seem to work effectively. Here is the code:

```
psf = np.ones((5, 5)) / 25
img = convolve2d(equ, psf, 'same')
img += 0.1 * img.std() * np.random.standard_normal(img.shape)
#deconvolved_img = restoration.wiener(img, psf, 1100)
deconvolved = restoration.wiener(img, psf, 1, clip=False)
plt.imshow(deconvolved, cmap='gray')
```

and this is the output:

[image]

Any help for the two problems is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For your Part 1 if you use `equ = cv2.cvtColor(equ, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)` you should get a 3 channel image but there are no colors, because all the channels have the same value as the gray image.

Comment: @LakshyaKejriwal But how would I go back to a `RGB` format then? I converted the image to `grayscale` in order to perform histogram equalization on it and from what I understand deblurring is also done on a `grayscale` version of the image

Comment: OpenCV doesn't have any in built function to colorize a grayscale image. For that you'll need to look into open source projects like [this](https://github.com/gustavla/autocolorize) that use deep learning.

Answer (score 3):

To equalize a color image, it seems a common thing to do is

- convert the image to HSV or YUV
- split the image into separate components (e.g. H, S, V)
- equalize on Value channel (or all three if you want)
- merge the channels back together

  ```
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  split = cv2.split(hsv)  # split is a 3D array containing H S V info
  split[2] = cv2.equalizeHist(split[2])
  hsv = cv2.merge(split)
  img = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
  ```

For "deblurring", I sometimes use an unsharp mask. From the [Wikipedia page on unsharp masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking#Digital_unsharp_masking), the formula for this operation is

> sharpened = original + (original − blurred) × amount

which can be rearranged to

> sharpened = original×(1 + amount) + blurred×(-amount)

Wikipedia says a good starting point for `amount` is 0.5 to 1.5. In my app I have a spinbox that let's it vary between 0 and 10. For blurring I use a Gaussian blur with kernel size varying from 1 to 31 (must be odd and integer). To do the matrix math, I prefer to use OpenCV functions because they are often faster than NumPy and they will usually autoscale output to values between 0 and 255 (e.g. for 8 bit and 8 bit/3 channel images). Here we use [addWeighted](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html) which does

> dst = src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma;

```
amount = 1.5
ksize = 3
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, ksize, 0, 0)
unsharp = cv.addWeighted(img, 1 + amount, blur, -amount, 0)
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! What would be your advice if I don't have the original image? I only have the blurred one.

Comment: @StefanoPozzi, the only way to get your original back is with a time machine or a backup. There is no historical information in raster files that I'm aware of. As a matter of course, you can imagine that it's a good idea to work on a renamed copy of the original file to prevent accidental overwriting. And believe me, we've all done it. If your original image was on a share on Windows file server, maybe you can get it back with Properties...Previous Versions. Best of luck.

Comment: This is actually an assignment that I was given to do for university. The assignment being `Take a (blurry) image with your phone (or a camera) and transfer it to your
computer. Perform some basic image analysis steps to enhance the image:
a) Histogram equalization (with comments and plots)
b) De-blurring (de-noising) of the image by application of a suitable filter (either on
space/frequency filed) and experiment with different choices and provide
comments.
c) Edge detection using one (or more) technique. `.

Comment: OK. If this is the assignment then there is no requirement for a "good" original image. It seems that the point of the assignment is to take a "bad" picture and do some image processing on it.