# Applying Wiener filter to remove noise using python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, wiener-filter

[image: This is the what my input image looks like]

[image: And this is what my wiener filtered output should look like]

The first image is my input image. The second image is a wiener filtered image, which is my output.

Below is the code to use wiener filter on my image. The input image is "img5" and the output image is "Wiener_filtered".

```
psf = np.ones((5,5)) / 25
img6 = convolve2d(img5,psf,'same')
img6 += 0.1 * img6.std() * np.random.standard_normal(img6.shape)
Wiener_filtered = restoration.wiener(img6,psf,1100)
```

Below I have attached the input image "img5" and the outcomes of "img6" and "Wiener_filtered"

[image: Input image img5]

Input image "img5"

[image: img6]

Outcome of "img6"

[image: Wiener_filtered]

The final wiener filtered image

I need help in finding out where i went wrong. I am new to image processing. Can someone show me the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out similar questions at SOF to get a better practical understanding of you to use the algorithm, e.g:

[Wiener Filter for image deblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192550/wiener-filter-for-image-deblur)

For improving your basic understanding of denoising, there are helpful tutorials availably for scipy and scikit-image, e.g.:

http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/#denoising

Answer (score 0):

Try to use : `img_as_float` from `skimage.util`. I think it should work :

```py
from skimage.util import img_as_float

img5 = img_as_float(img5)
psf = np.ones((5,5)) / 25
img6 = convolve2d(img5,psf,'same')
img6 += 0.1 * img6.std() * np.random.standard_normal(img6.shape)
Wiener_filtered = restoration.wiener(img6,psf,1100)
```